# Does there need to be the same number of parameters passed into a javascript function as the number defined in the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, stripe-payments

I could do with some javascript function help.

The code below is an example from stripe using node.js and basically is posting a code back to stripe to get some user details.

```
app.get('/oauth/callback', function(req, res) {

  var code = req.query.code;

  // Make /oauth/token endpoint POST request
  request.post({
    url: TOKEN_URI,
    form: {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      code: code,
      client_secret: API_KEY
    }
  }
});
```

I need to set up a similar function but the main difference is that I already have that code and want to pass the code into the function.

At the moment my function looks like:

```
var getAccountDetails = function(req, res) {

  // Make /oauth/token endpoint POST request
  request.post({
    url: 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token';,
    form: {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      client_id: 'ca_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      code: code,
      client_secret: API_KEY
    }
  }, function(err, r, body) {


  });
};
```

I am calling getAccountDetails() from within another function but wanted to pass in to getAccountDetails(code) but i'm still struggling a little with javascript functions.

*************** Update **************

On the google cloud function console i keep getting a timeout message. If anyone sees anything obviously wrong with the code let me know.

```
function getAccountDetails(code)
{
   console.log(code)
 return  function(req, res) {

  // Make /oauth/token endpoint POST request
  request.post({
    url: 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token',
    form: {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      client_id: 'xxxxxxxxx',
      code: code,
      client_secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
  }, function(err, r, body) {

   // var accessToken = JSON.parse(body).access_token;

    console.log(body);
  });
}
}

exports.authCode = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log(req)

  var code = req.query.code;

  console.log(code);

  getAccountDetails(code)

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at closure

Comment: After your update, @floatingLomas' answer below looks like it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your title question is no. Javascript is very flexible about whether the number of arguments in a function definition match the number of arguments passed in when calling the function.

Handling differing numbers of arguments is handled like this:

- If a function is invoked with fewer arguments than in the definition, the arguments not included will be `undefined` in the function execution.
- If a function is invoked with more arguments than in the definition, the excess arguments don't cause any problems

In fact, in the second case, you can still access the extra arguments passed in using the `arguments` keyword:

```
function example(p1, p2) {
    console.log(arguments[2]);
}

example('one', 'two', 'three'); // logs: 'three'
```

---

However, the function you are using looks like it may be part of a framework. How you can use it depends on what framework, and where it is in that framework.

You can modify the function definition:

```
var getAccountDetails = function(req, res, code) {
    // ...
```

and this is fine as long as no other part of the framework is calling that function, possibly expecting something else to be there in that third argument (for ex, lots of express-based apps might be expecting the third argument to be a callback function, often labelled `next`, etc).

As a best guess, if you created this function as a helper, or service for yourself, then I would say modify it as needed and experiment. However, if it's in a highly structured part of a framework, modifying it may break something.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
exports.authCode = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log(req)

  var code = req.query.code;

  console.log(code);

  getAccountDetails(code)(req, res);
});
```

`getAccountDetails(code)` is returning a Function that expects `(req, res)`, so you just need to call that Function with the `req` and `res` provided.  Since you're not actually calling that Function, nothing is happening - you're not doing anything with `res` - so it's timing out.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript a function (A) can return another functions (B). The function B returned can remember whatever the function A was called with. This is called closures. So

```
function getAccoudnDetailsWith(code) {
  return function (req, res) { //this function is stored in getAccountDetails
    request.post({
      url: 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token',
      form: {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        client_id: 'ca_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        code: code,///this code is whatever you pass in
        client_secret: API_KEY
      }
  }, function (err, r, body) {


    });
  }
}

var getAccountDetails = getAccoudnDetailsWith(code);
```

Edit 1:
You wouldn't need closures for this from your changed code.

```
exports.authCode = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  var code = req.query.code;

  // Make /oauth/token endpoint POST request
  request.post({
    url: TOKEN_URI,
    form: {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      code: code,
      client_secret: API_KEY
    }
  }, function(err, r, body) {

       // var accessToken = JSON.parse(body).access_token;

        console.log(body);
      });
});
```

Comment: Hey @Shyam. I tried the above but I keep getting a timeout message. I updated my original post - if you see anything wrong let me know! Thx